# Changing the color of LaTeX command

Tags: latex

I'm trying to use `\texttt{...}`, but I want to change the color it uses to gray. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{\color{gray}\texttt{text}}` to get gray typewriter font.

However if you want to use this to show some kind of code, it would be better to have a look at the `listings` package. This allows you to globally change the colour:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\color{gray}\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

{\color{gray}\texttt{text}}

\lstinline|text|

\end{document}
```